# I Can not merge my work into develop branch using SourceTree?

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree instead of using commandlines, I am having a very weird problem, I don't know from where it is coming, I reinstalled SourceTree and it seems nothing is working, What I used to do is to work in my branch, commit and push my work and if want to merge something from other branch I click on it, then I click right and choose 'Merge' option and that how I merge, But Now it seems like I am not able to do so .. and also it looks like my branch is isolated or something, I can't see other peope pushes, I see only mine

[image]

And when I click now on develop I am waiting for Sourcetree to point on the 'last' of develop after all, so I can click on the right and choose merge to merge develop into my branche but it is not possible now, I get this message ( loading message ) That I was not used to see it.

[image]

What should I do ? any help would be much appreciated.
If there any others solution so i can merge my work into develop or something help me, I really need this. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you still able to push to remote? Is it possible that you "lost" your remote configuration. That would explain nothing coming in anymore. Maybe you want to add your .git/config? Are you working on github? What do you see in the webgui?